# force twitter bootstrap to use mobile menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to force the collapsing menu on every mobile device, not depending on the screenresolution. With asp.net mvc 4 I can check if I have a mobile device, if so I want to force the collapsing mobile menu from bootstrap. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to override the default media queries in order to get `navbar-collapse` to remain visible at all times. For example, you'll find this on line 4296 of Bootstrap 3's style.css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

This hides the button when the browser window exceeds 768px. So rather than hide it, change display to `block`. Poke around and play with the other elements, like `navbar-nav`. It's the same principle.

Comment: I would recommend not messing with "core" bootstrap. Rather, you should override their styles in your own stylesheet. Makes things a lot smoother when they decide to update. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#customizing. Otherwise, looks good.

Comment: I just created a second one and import it depending on the the `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice`

Answer (score 1):

its not recommended to so it - but i did this the other day for a mobile app.

i have bootstrap.min.css and just did a find replace for 768px and replaced with 3000px.

this has the effect of forcing the menu to not hide until => 3000px